# rm -rf and rmdir both giving error cannot remove, directory not empty

Tags: 14.04, directory, delete, rm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I am user jason.  I tried the commands below with `sudo` but it didn't work.

here are the commands given.

```
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans$ rm -rf Movies/*
rm: cannot remove ‘Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]’: Directory not empty
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans$ cd Movies/Sex*
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ ls
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 jason jason 4096 Sep 26 05:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 jason jason 4096 Sep 26 05:35 ..
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ cd ../
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies$ rmdir S*
rmdir: failed to remove ‘Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]’: Directory not empty
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans$ rm -rf Movies/*
rm: cannot remove ‘Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]’: Directory not empty
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans$ cd Movies/Sex* 
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ ls
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 jason jason 4096 Sep 26 05:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 jason jason 4096 Sep 26 05:35 ..
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies/Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]$ cd ../
jason@TRZG001:~/plex/trans/Movies$ rmdir S*
rmdir: failed to remove ‘Sex After Kids (2013) [1080p]’: Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 2):

found the problem.  The folder was the unencrpyted folder used in encfs.  an unencrypted file was written into the encrypted version located in folder .trans.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to solve this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) Also, please edit your question to mention how the EncFS is involved here; it was obviously an important part of the issue.